# Accessing MVC 3 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I had a solution with mvc 3 site (this site is set as startup project). I then added another mvc 3 site into this solution so now I have two mvc 3 sites but startup project is still the same.

if I run first site evrything is ok, if then I change startup project on second site also everything is ok.

Now i added reference of second mvc 3 site to the first and added @Html.ActionLink("LinkToSecondSite", "Index", "Second") link in my index page so that when I will run first site I would like to have link to my second site. The domain will be the same in the end. Is this actually possible and "right" thing to do or are there any compile or runtime problems?

Tnx for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [action link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) overload which takes hostname and fragment. Something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
   this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
   string linkText,
   string actionName,
   string controllerName,
   string protocol,
   string hostName,
   string fragment,
   Object routeValues,
   Object htmlAttributes
  )
```

Comment: As I know if you have more than one mvc 3 page in solution each page runs on diffrent port. Lets say the main on localhost:4000 and the second on localhost:4500. How do you assign diffrent port number. I tried this @Html.ActionLink("Forum", "Index", "Board", "http", "localhost", null, null, null) but the port is 4000 instead of 4500. It looks like that port is assigned automatically.